# How to close Ionic selects on page redirect?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using `ng-idle` to redirect the user back to the home screen if the app isn't used within 60 seconds.

The problem I have is that if there is an ion-select popover open at the time of redirecting, these are still displayed on the screen until they are manually closed. Is there any way of detecting any open popovers and closing them all?

I've seen that you can reference ion-select like so:

`@ViewChild('myselect') select: Select;`

but my select fields are setup dynamically in a form so there's no way of knowing how many select fields will be set up.

I have also tried removing the `<ion-alert></ion-alert>` elements manually with javascript, but for some reason this prevents the user from opening the ion-select popovers when they start to use the app again.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you have a dynamic amount of fields, you can use `ViewChildren` instead of `ViewChild`.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that existed! I've got it working now and will post up my answer shortly incase it helps anyone else.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it was helpful! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alex's comment, this is how I solved the problem:

**Imports**

```
import { QueryList, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { Select } from 'ionic-angular';
```

**ViewChildren Setup**

```
@ViewChildren(Select) viewChildren: QueryList<Select>;
```

**When the page is left, close any open ion-select fields.**

```
ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.viewChildren.map((view:any) => {
      view.close();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone looking for a solution in Ionic v5, here is the solution.

```
let backDrop = document.querySelector('ion-backdrop');

if (backDrop) {
  backDrop.click();
}
```

As the IonSelect does not have close() in v4 and v5, this is a possible way.

Answer (score 0):

> Adding to @Atheesh27 answer:

If you have a lot of ion-select modals open, you can dismiss all by repeating the backDrop.click() event and wait some seconds to close the next like this:

HTML

```
  <ion-select  (ionCancel)="cancelarSeleccion()" >
        
          <ion-select-option > option </ion-select-option>
        </section>
    </ion-select>
```

TS

```
     delay(n){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        setTimeout(resolve,n*1000);
    });
  }


async cancelarSeleccion(){

    
    let backDrop = document.querySelector('ion-backdrop');
    backDrop.click();

    await this.delay(.1);

    let backDrop1 = document.querySelector('ion-backdrop');
    backDrop1.click();

    await this.delay(.1);

    let backDrop2 = document.querySelector('ion-backdrop');
    backDrop2.click();


  }
```